# Cocoa Pods with google calendar api

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, google-calendar-api

I am following the instructions on the google calendar api for iOS web page. 
See link. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ios?ver=objc#step_2_prepare_the_workspace

When I follow these terminal commands

```
cat << EOF > Podfile &&
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'GoogleAPIClient/Calendar', '~> 1.0.2'
pod 'GTMOAuth2', '~> 1.1.0'
EOF
pod install &&
open QuickstartApp.xcworkspace
```

I get the following error

```
[!] The dependency `GoogleAPIClient/Calendar (~> 1.0.2)` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `GTMOAuth2 (~> 1.1.0)` is not used in any concrete target.
```

I am not sure why this is happening. My project has a different name then QuickstartApp but I don't think this is causing the errors.

Comment: I think Google needs to update their docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably create the Podfile the way [Cocoapods recommends](https://cocoapods.org/#get_started).

Yours should probably look like:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'GoogleAPIClient/Calendar', '~> 1.0.2' 
    pod 'GTMOAuth2', '~> 1.1.0
end
```

Now run `pod install` then open you Xcode workspace.

One of the recent changes for Cocoapods was that [targets need to be named](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.0-Migration-Guide/).